# Image Markdown trips the code formatting alarm

Tags: bug

The lack of line breaks between Markdown lines for images causes the code formatting monitor to go on high alert.

Alarm:
[image]

No Alarm:
[image]

I don't have this problem on Superuser. Bug?

Comment: Yes, this is a duplicate question. Regrettably! I did try to see if there are other reports of this, but I could not find one. Oddly this is not a problem on Superuser, and I have created a number of how-to guides using medium sized images as gallery thumbnails on a single line for my many screenshots.

Comment: "Oddlly"? I suppose SO receives way more unformatted code than SU.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose you're right. But this can and should be improved nonetheless. It's not a high priority issue though.

Comment: It seems like you can add 2 images next to each other. But once you add 1 more you run into trouble with the big Red.